# Delete Action does not activate/trigger ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, razor

HttpPost on delete action does not trigger, however HttpGet seems working fine as i get the content displayed. However I have little confusion in the following route address generated when I click on HttpGet on delete action:-

https://localhost:44394/9

shouldn't it generates link like this: https://localhost:44394/Post/DeletePost/9

Controller:-

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("DeletePost")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ConfirmDelete(int id)
{          
     await _repository.DeletePostAsync(id);             
     return RedirectToAction(nameof(GetAllPosts));           
 }
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeletePost(int id)
{
  var post = await _repository.GetPostById(id);
  if(post == null)
   {
     return NotFound();
   }
    return View(post);
}
```

Razor View for HttpGet:-

```
 <div class="btn btn-outline-danger delete">
    <a href="@Url.Action("DeletePost", "Post", new { id = p.Id })">Delete
    </a>
</div>
```

Razor Page HttpPost:-

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-9">
            <p>
                @Model.Topic
            </p>
            <p class="timeStampValue" data-value="@Model.Published">
                @Model.Published
            </p>
            <p>
                @Model.Author
            </p>
            <section>
                <markdown markdown="@Model.Content" />
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>

    <form asp-action="DeletePostAsync"> 
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Delete</button>
    </form>
    <a href="@Url.Action("GetAllPosts", "Post")" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Cancel</a>
</div>
```

Routing:-

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{     routes.MapRoute(
      name: "KtsPost",
      template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Post", action = "Index" },
     constraints: new { id = "[0-9]+" });
      });
```

Answer (score 2):

Your action name is wrong in the form. Your code should be instead:

```
<form asp-action="DeletePost"> 
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The default method of an HTML form is `GET` not `POST`. You need to tell your form to `POST`. Also, the action name should be `ConfirmDelete`:

```
<form asp-action="ConfirmDelete" method="post"> 
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and help, however i have already tried all these steps that you have suggested. In fact my HttpPost ActionName is DeletePost, shouldn't it trigger the method "ConfirmDelete", though i changed it as you suggested but does not make any different. When I tried to debug not it does not trigger HttpPost action method..